# Sending a parsed array to processing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, processing

I want to send an array of Integers from a php file named load.php to a JS script that will in turn send it to a Processing file written in js.

In the load.php i create the array i want to send and send it using json (the array consists of at least 40 Integers):

```
echo json_encode($varsArray);
```

In the main php file named game.php is the script:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function js_GetArray() {
    $.get( "load.php", function( actiondata ) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(actiondata);
        return obj;
    });
}
```

Using this script i request the array from load.php (which I receive in json format), after receiving i parse it and send it back to the processing file.

In the Processing file I receive the array as such:

```
var objArr;
void setup(){
    objArr = js_GetArray();

}
void draw() {  
    alert(objArr[1]);
}
```

When activating the alert I receive the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

How can I solve this and is there a better way to send the array?

Thank you.

Comment: @ClémentMalet That part was written manually to cut out all the other code before and after, it was written properly in the code itself and sends the error regardless.

Comment: The problem is that `$.get` is asynchromous, so it can't make `js_GetArray` return `obj`, because the callback function where you build `obj` will be executed later.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is twofold.

1. Your `js_GetArray` function doesn't actually return your data.
   You are actually returning the data from the callback passed to `$.get`, not from the `js_GetArray` function
2. Asynchronous execution is going to cause you problems.  This is what happens in javascript commonly, is that you pass a callback function, which is called back later when the given process is finished.   `$.get` has to make a request to a webserver and return the content.  This can't happen instantly, so javascript *calls you back* with the results when it's done.

So, you are not getting the data until `$.get` calls the callback.

You need to do something like:

```
var objArr;

function js_GetArray(callback) {
    $.get( "load.php", function( actiondata ) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(actiondata);
        callback(obj);
    });
}

void setup(){
    js_GetArray(function(data) {
        objArray = data;
    });
}
void draw() {  
    alert(objArr[1]);
}
```

You may want to read about how asynchronous code works in javascript.
Here's one article:

http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: No comments to explain the downvote?  Comments help us improve answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. AJAX means "**ASYNCHRONOUS** Javascript and XML". That said, your `draw` function executes while the ajax call is still in progress. Thus, the `objArr` is still empty then.

Put call to `draw` in the callback:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function js_GetArray() {
    $.get( "load.php", function( actiondata ) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(actiondata);
        // return obj; doesn't work!
        draw ( obj );
    });
}

void draw(objArr) {  
  alert(objArr[1]);
}
```

Comment: Using the callback method does manage to send the array to the processing but like you said, it still goes through one draw loop in which it is undefined. - I might have misunderstood what you meant but adding the draw to the callback actually causes me to receive the undefined reply every time.

Comment: Nicely explained.  However, I *think* that `draw` is called by processing, so this won't work.